# How can I get the value from an <html:select> tag?

Tags: java, html, jsp, jsp-tags, struts-1

This is my markup:

```
<html:select property="customername" styleClass="select2" style="width:100% tabindex=-1" onclick="alert('hai')" styleId="customer_tree">
<logic:iterate name="namelist" id="namelistId" indexId="i">
<html:option value='${i+1}'><bean:write name="namelistId"/></html:option>
</logic:iterate>
```

I get this error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find bean: "namelist" in any scope

this is my Bean class:

```
private String customername;
private String imeino;
private String targetname;
private String simno;
private String duedate;
private String remark;
private String error;

public String getCustomername() {
    return customername;
}

public void setCustomername(String customername) {
    this.customername = customername;
}

public String getImeino() {
    return imeino;
}

public void setImeino(String imeino) {
    this.imeino = imeino;
}

public String getTargetname() {
    return targetname;
}

public void setTargetname(String tergetname) {
    this.targetname = tergetname;
}

public String getSimno() {
    return simno;
}

public void setSimno(String simno) {
    this.simno = simno;
}

public String getDuedate() {
    return duedate;
}

public void setDuedate(String duedate) {
    this.duedate = duedate;
}

public String getRemark() {
    return remark;
}

public void setRemark(String remark) {
    this.remark = remark;
}

public String getError() {
    return error;
}

public void setError(String error) {
    this.error = error;
}
```

when i use normal  tag without using  tag, i got output but use above coding i got above exception. what can i do?

This is my action class:

```
List<String> name_list = new ArrayList<String>();

        Query enc_password = session.createQuery("from account_dao");
        List list = enc_password.list();
        for (Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            account_dao account = (account_dao) iterator.next();
            System.out.println("Id : " + account.getId());
            System.out.println("Account Name : " + account.getName());
            System.out.println("Account Password : " + account.getPassword());
            name_list.add(account.getName());
        }
        request.setAttribute("namelist", name_list);

        return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
```

Comment: it says in this scope there is not bean namelist,pls show the code where you set the beane namelist value.

Comment: I think it's clear states that no bean with name `namelist` found.

Comment: i add my coding sir, pls check it. am waiting.........

Comment: this is bean but where do you put or attach the bean to scope like request or session something like that?

Comment: @KannanPriya Have you gone through this ?? http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-logic-iterate-example/

Comment: i add my action class sir, please........

Comment: May be problem because of the IDE is not rebulid the classes.please check by stop server,rebulid the project and check. Code seems to be ok.

Comment: After rebuild, i got same error. how can i get value from <html:select> tag inside <logic:iterate> tag?